# how are bridges handled in ARP?

Tags: ipv4, ip, mac-address, arp

assume want to send a packet from H1 to H3 and we have a network like this:

```
**H1**
A:a
|
|
N
**B1** E --- E:e **R1** F:f--- C:c**H3**
S
|
|
B:b
**H2**
```

How will ARP table look for these nodes in the network ?
i know how ARP works and how the tables are filled but not sure how to think when there is bridges?

For example if we had a network like this:

**H1** A:a --- C:c **R1** D:d --- B:b **H2**

then then the tables would look like this:

H1 table => ip:C mac:c

R1 table => ip:A mac:a and ip:B mac:b

H2 table => ip:D mac:d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transparent bridge, e.g. ethernet switch, has no effect on ARP. A translating bridge, e.g. ethernet/token ring bridge, may change a MAC address between canonical and non-canonical or have some other effect, based on what it is bridging.

Comment: do the bridges have tables as well ? what do they contain if they have tables? based on the network layout provided above

Comment: Bridges don't have ARP tables because bridges are layer-2 devices. ARP resolves layer-3 addresses to layer-2 addresses. Bridges have MAC address tables which translate from a MAC address to a bridge interface, but a bridge gets that information from each incoming frame.

Comment: alright, assuming we want to send a packet from H1 to H3, how will the table for H1 for example look like ? will H1´s table only contain ip:E mac:e ?

Comment: Well, you said you know how ARP works, so you know that the ARP table for H1 will contain the IP and MAC addresses of its directly connected layer-3 devices (routers and hosts). It will not have the IP and MAC addresses of H3 since there is a layer-3 separation between H1 and H3.

Comment: By ip:E mac:e  i was referring to R1, So yeah H1 table will contain the direct address to R1 but will not have the address to H2... right ? please feel free to correct me if i am worng

Comment: It may have the IP and MAC addresses for H2. ARP requests are broadcast, and all hosts listen for them to build their ARP tables. If H2 had any traffic, H1 should have listened to the ARP request from H2 and installed it into its own ARP table.

Comment: assuming that all the tables are empty in the beginning, and the only traffic is going from H1, to H3 then we can say that H1 dont have the address for H2

Comment: That would be correct.

Comment: Great explanation, my question is answered. But one little side question, i read that bridges have state ? if that is correct, what does the state say about the bridge and what changes the state ?

Comment: That is a whole discussion on spanning tree. Spanning tree ports have a state. Do some research on spanning tree to see if you have a particular question.

Comment: Alright will do. another thing, as you mentioned above, Bridges don't have ARP tables but they do have "the learning table" which is a table to keep track of stations connected to it. for example B1 have a table that contain mac address for H1 and R1, correct ?

Comment: It will have an entry for any source address of any frame which entered the bridge. That would include the ARP request from H1 and the ARP response from R1.